# How to Set Anchor to YES in all Categories in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I followed 
https://steemit.com/magento/@meetanshi/how-to-set-anchor-to-yes-in-all-categories-in-magento-2

It work, but i have more store view. In my catalog_category_entity_int table there is no attribute = 43 for store_id = 2 or 3. How to set is anchor to yes for all category in all store. Please help me

UPDATE

I can't find category id = 316 in catalog_category_entity? Where is i can find it?

Comment: what you get when you runt the querie https://meetanshi.d.pr/M0VLGT

Comment: attribute_id = 43.

Comment: SELECT * FROM `catalog_category_entity_int` WHERE `attribute_id`=43 please run this queries you get the record or not?

Comment: yes, it's ok. 283 row updated. but it not work in all category for all store.

Comment: Please clear the cache and check , because if row effacted than it definatli work

Comment: i cleaned cache but it not work :((

Comment: What changed is from store id = 0, I have 7 store id. For example, if a store has 283 categories, it must change 1981 rows

Comment: but it fetch 283 row , we not pass the filter of store specific in the queries to select the row

Comment: what you get when you runt the querie drops.meetanshi.com/M0VLGT

Comment: what you get when you runt the querie drops.meetanshi.com/M0VLGT

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve this by running the below queries in your database.

First, identify the attribute id of the `is_anchor` attribute with below query:

```
SELECT * FROM eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'is_anchor';
```

From this, you've got the attribute id. After this, you need to run the below query to update all category to Anchor YES.

```
UPDATE catalog_category_entity_int set value = 1 where attribute_id = 54;
```

Where **`54`** is the attribute id for `is_anchor`.

**Hope it helps!!!**

Comment: This is the same as what I did, but it doesn't work properly for all categories

Comment: I've checked this on my store and it will changed the values for all store views. Please run the re-index process and flush the caches on your website.

Comment: What changed is from store id = 0, I have 7 store id. For example, if a store has 283 categories, it must change 1981 rows

Comment: How many entries do you've in catalog_category_entity_int WHERE attribute_id=43?

Comment: only 283 rows for store id = 0. Only store id = 0 has attribute_id = 43

Comment: As I've checked this, is_anchor attribute is a global attribute for the categories and it'll save under store_id 0. So the is_anchor value is set globally for all the categories if you run the above query.

Comment: if so, why doesn't it work for me?

Comment: Have you run the re-index process on your website?

Comment: yes, i runed it and clean cache

Comment: In admin, the is_anchor attribute value for the other stores is Yes or No?

Comment: no, it don't set. but, i have category id = 316, i can't find it in catalod_category_entity? it show no rows

Comment: Is your database selection for running the above queries is same which configured with your website? Please cross check once.

Comment: Can you say clearer?

Comment: Cross-check database name from the PHP my admin in which you run the above queries and the database using by your website.

Comment: LOL, I did it on the database test. Thank you for the answer, have a nice day  Sumit